# How can I launch Android Studio tests with a batch file?

Tags: android, android-studio, batch-file

So I have an Android project for which I created a test. But I'd like to run this test multiple times in series. So I thought that it is perhaps possible to run a test scenario from the command line and write it into a .bat file. But I can't really find any solutions that I can understand. (I'm quite new to Android Studio.)

So is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: Is your question about how to use Android Studio or how to write a `.bat` file. In either case as your question currently stands it is off topic here! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46693064/edit) to include the code you have written, tried and are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANT jars ant.jar and ant-launcher.jar

Please go through the documentation [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)